# Using file as middle layer while transferring data from MySql to NoSql in Java

Tags: java, file-handling

I am currently doing my project on Migrating data from MySql to NoSql using Java as programming language. Following are the process involved in it:

- Reads MySql data and writes into file in Json format
- Reads the Json file and writes into NoSql
- Writes the error log if any error occurs in any of the above process

However, the migration can be done without using the file as intermediate layer. I found many of the tools and thesis works are done in the above design therefore I just followed it. Is there any benefit using file as a middle layer instead of migrating directly?

Comment: I posted an answer but realized after posting it that some clarification may be required... Is there any physical (hardware) restrictions? Such as processing or storage, network, etc?

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr, there can be restriction of storage and bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question outright: Yes there is benefits, but it depends on your overall implementation.

**Here are a couple things to consider (as to why it could be an asset).**

1. Integrity in case of failure. Depending on how the process runs, if something terrible happens during the transfer, having the files shows you where/why a problem occurred.
2. If your databases are physically separated the files would save you a lot of overhead traffic between servers.
3. Generally easier to debug a file then a process. It is easy to see the problem when exporting to a somewhat readable file, versus tracking down the same bug at runtime.

**Reasons against:**

1. Files take up extra space you may not want to use.
2. Slower overall (since this in effect requires reading database, save to file, load from file, write to database).
3. It adds an extra point of failure. You have to read and write to the database, and convert into a usable format regardless of file implementation. However the added layer of using a file increases the risk of failure (such as missing files, corrupted, too large, etc).

Since storage and bandwidth are a concern in your situation, here would be my recommendation. If you have enough storage to accommodate the files during the transfer (e.g. they are temporary) then transfer using files as it will save you bandwidth. Deleting the files afterwards makes storage less of an issue.

Comment: @sh4dowsPlyr, would you suggest me what should be done if the migration is done in local machine and if the migration is done across the servers?

Comment: Local Machine - Direct Transfer, Remote - File Transfer. If you have physical access to both machines you could manually transfer the files to save the bandwidth but that may be tedious. However after thinking more about it my recommendation is more to the file methodology in general.